# Error response from daemon: Container xxxxxxxxxx... is not running

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I´m trying to create an image in docker for my container. This image must have python 3.10 version, ubuntu last version and git. I´ve created the nex Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y git && \
    apt-get install -y python3.10 && \
    apt-get clean

EXPOSE 6379
```

Once created y saved it in a new directory and opend that directory in windows powershel and executed the next command to create the image: `docker build -t py3_10 .`

It creates the image without problems, then I create the container `docker run -d -p 6379:6379 --name pyth py3_10` and it does it without error. But, when i try to execute the container `docker exec -it pyth bash` the next error appears: `Error response from daemon: Container a5ffdf1112f24c3... is not running`

Shoul I change something or add something in the Dockerfile?

Comment: 6379 assigned to redis.  Did you mean to run redis on this container?  generally you'd want to run redis on one container and python in another

Comment: @erik258 no i don´t want redis, i copied the port from an example, i`m changing it now, thanks

Comment: @erik258 changed, but still having the same error. Do I need to add something like CMD ["bash"] at the end of the Dockerfile?

Comment: yeah the port isn't breaking anything.  You can also omit `-p ...` if you don't need to open that port.  See my answer below for a solution.

Comment: That Dockerfile doesn't seem to `COPY` in the application code, `RUN pip install`, or set its `CMD` to run the Python application.  Docker's [Build your Python image](https://docs.docker.com/language/python/build-images/) tutorial has a typical setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Error response from daemon: Container a5ffdf1112f24c3... is not running`

Docker containers exist for the lifetime of their entrpoint process.  Your dockerfile has no `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` to keep running.  You can set one in the Dockerfile.

If the CMD / ENTRYPOINT is a shell like bash, you will need to allocate a terminal to keep it running.  Otherwise the shell will dutifully close at end of input.

You could try something like this:

```
docker run -it -d  --entrypoint bash py3_10
```

> But, when i try to execute the container

When you try to execute *additional commands* in container context. `run` runs the container, and when `run`'s process ends, the container stops.  `exec` only works in the mean time.

I recommend thinking of containers as runtimes, not development environments.     Seems like you think of the container as a virtual machine that you would shell into to do python 10 development.  Instead think of it as a set of libraries providing python 10 to whatever code you want to run there.   Dockerfiles are generally project specific, and would include commands to `ADD` / `COPY` the project's codebase into the container, install dependencies, and then the entrypoint would be the invocation of the project's main executable.

Comment: Thanks it works like this. One more thing, in the command `docker run -it -d --entrypoint bash py3_10` can i add a name for the container or it is created with a random name?

Comment: Yeah, you can always mix and max the command line parameters.  You can replace `--entrypoint` with an ENTRYPOINT or CMD delcaration in the Dockerfile if you care to.

Answer (score -2):

You need, to add this line at the end of your Dockerfile

```bash
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
```

Because your container, starts, installs its dependancies and then... it has nothing to do any more so it ends.
With this line, it will run a bash, and then your `docker exec -it` will be able to "attach" to it

Hope it helps

Comment: `SHELL` won't provide an entrypoint or command to run, just [sets the default shell](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell)